# Why 64 + 12 = 82

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, review

[image]

But my reviewing stats show 82 edit reviews:

[image]

Is it a bug or I misunderstood something?

Comment: Deleted posts most likely, or maybe own posts.

Comment: Deleted posts still count towards the review totals.

Comment: I don't think the marked duplicate is a duplicate of this; it's asking why suggested edits count is higher than badge progress towards copy editor. This is asking why progress towards reviewer is more than combined actions taken.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yeah, really. You have chosen a wrong question to mark my as a dup. Thanks 3ventic for noticing.

Comment: @3ventic fair enough, was too eager to use the hammer I guess. But I'm 99% sure there is a dupe somewhere.

Comment: @ShadowWizard "there is a dupe somewhere." So you will mark *it* as a dupe of *mine*, not vice-versa, **REMEMBER**.

Comment: @Shadow I found it, and I answered that one too. ;P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have approved 64, rejected 12 **and edited 6** edit suggestions. (64+12+6=82) When you choose to edit, the approval/rejection is attributed to Community ♦, so it doesn't increment those counters for you.

Comment: Ok, understood.